# `Either` with a Semigroup on the left

Tags: haskell, hackage

Does something like this already exist or should I package it up for Hackage (I find it useful for collecting errors):

```
module EitherSemigroup where

import Prelude hiding (Right, Left)
import Data.Semigroup (Semigroup)

data EitherSemigroup l r = Left l | Right r

instance Functor (EitherSemigroup l) where
  fmap f (Right x) = Right (f x)
  fmap _ (Left x) = Left x

instance Semigroup l => Applicative (EitherSemigroup l) where
  pure = Right
  (<*>) (Right f) (Right x) = Right (f x)
  (<*>) (Right _) (Left x) = Left x
  (<*>) (Left x) (Right _) = Left x
  (<*>) (Left x1) (Left x2) = Left (x1 <> x2)

instance Semigroup l => Monad (EitherSemigroup l) where
  (>>=) (Right x) f = f x
  (>>=) (Left x) _ = Left x
```

It's worth noting that the `Applicative` and `Monad` instances for `(,)` are very similar to this but for a product type, which does the job for collecting "warnings".

If I do package it up for Hackage I'd probably add more instances but if someone has already done this I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Your `Monad` instance doesn't match your `Applicative` one. I don't think it can. Not a `Monad`.

Comment: I was a little worried about that, why doesn't the `Monad` instance match `Applicative`? What's the law I'm breaking?

Comment: You're breaking the law that `(<*>) = ap`.