# Combining Either and Pair monads with transformers

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I haven't used monad transformers before but I think it's what I need in my case. Here's some sample code below:

```
Prelude> (+) <$> Right 2 <*> Right 3
Right 5

Prelude> (+) <$> (['a'],2) <*> (['b'],3)
("ab",5)
```

But I want to combine these two behaviours like so:

```
Prelude> (+) <$> Right ("a",2) <*> Right ("b",3)
Right ("ab",5)
```

Naturally this fails to compile as numeric addition is not defined on `(String, Int)`.

The [Monad transformers Haskell wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers) suggests I need to use a transformer for the inner monad, which is in this case a pair, but searching for PairT on [Hayoo!](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=PairT) or [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=PairT) didn't reveal anything relevant.

Do I have to implement this transformer myself, or is there something on Hackage I've missed, or am I just misunderstanding how this should be done?

**Note:**

The actual outer monad I'm using isn't `Either`, it's a custom monad I've detailed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44403117/either-with-a-semigroup-on-the-left), which however is quite similar to `Either`.

Answer (score 3):

In the example, we are combining actions in an "applicative" way, meaning that each action does not depend on the returning value of a previous action.

Turns out that `Applicative`s compose better than `Monad`s: instead of needing a different "transformer" type for each `Applicative`, we can use a common [`Compose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) newtype to create a composite effect for any two `Applicative`s:

```
ghci> import Data.Functor.Compose
ghci> getCompose $ (+) <$> Compose (Right ("a",2)) <*> Compose (Right ("b",3))
Right ("ab",5)
```

The effects of the "outermost" `Applicative` (`Either` in this case) have priority.

There is some noise in the wrapping/unwrapping of the newtype. If we want to avoid the newtype noise and the operators, we could also modify *chi*'s answer and do something like

```
liftA2 (liftA2 (+)) (Right ("a",2)) (Right ("b",3))
```

The "outer" `liftA2` works on the `Either`, the "inner" `liftA2` works on `(,) String`.

Comment: What if I have `Left "error"` and `Right 2` and want the result to be `Left "error"`?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar If I understand correctly, it should work that way already.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative:

```
> liftA2 (+) <$> Right ("a",2) <*> Right ("b",3)
Right ("ab",5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, I think the Pair monad transformer is [`WriterT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:WriterT). In the example above, the type you're looking for is

```
WriterT String (Either l) Int
```

`String` should be replaced by whatever is on the right hand side of the pairs.
`l` should be whatever the type of `Left` is.
`Int` should be replaced by whatever the result type is.

Comment: Be careful with using  `WriterT String`. First remember that `String = [Char]`, so the monoid instance for lists apply. For lists, `mappend = (++)`. And remember that `n ++ m` has runtime complexity: `O(n)`. When you do this over and over again, the complexity becomes `O(n^2)`. Therefore, you should use difference lists instead: https://kseo.github.io/posts/2014-01-14-difference-listfor-writer-monad.html

Comment: Also, given that `Either e a = Except e a = ExceptT e Identity a` do note that `WriterT w (Except e) /= ExceptT e (Writer w)`. The former has no log when there's an exception, and the latter always has a log, even on exception.